# The number of apples, the number of oranges, the numbers of apples and oranges?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

When we count objects, we can say

- The number of apples is two.
- The number of oranges is three.

I am wondering how to combine these two sentences.

Can I say that:

The number(s) of apples and oranges is five.

I want to know if I need "s" in numbers (because I am talking two different numbers).

Or can I say:

The number(s) of apples and oranges are different.

The number(s) of apples and oranges are two and three.

Comment: How can you use "numbers" when you only have one number (five)?

Comment: @user3169 Ok, that makes sense. I added one more sentence. In that case, do I need "s"?

Comment: I added another.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "the number of" emphasizes a *precise* quantity. It is used when *the exact number* is important, not just the fact that there are many (it would be *a number of* then) and it takes a plural noun followed by a *singular* verb. So it would be:

> The number of apples and oranges is five.
>
> The number of apples and oranges is two and three (respectively).

This agrees with the basic rule of [Subject-Verb Agreement](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp):

A singular subject (here - the number) takes a singular verb (here - is).

Comment: Why not "amount"?

Comment: Wouldn't "The numbers of apples and oranges" be a request for separate counts of apples and oranges (multiple numbers)?  It's clunky, but wouldn't it be technically correct?